# Generic Repository with different databases, entity types and dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, generics

I have implemented a simple generic repository for my asp.net web api project following this easy to follow guide :

http://www.dataworks.ie/blog/entity_framework_5_with_automapper_and_repository_pattern

That works fine.

However my solution in development has two simple databases with the same schema - a SQL Server CE for test/dev and when running local (and offline) and a SQL Azure when online. Both have EF layers created in separate assemblies. I switch the `DbContext` via the `web.config` connection string in the constructor of  the context class. The problem is with my controller code.

For e.g. if using Azure I would have

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IGenericRepository<MyProj.Data.SqlAzure.User> userRepo = new GenericRepository<MyProj.Data.SqlAzure.User>();
```

if I'm using SQL Server CE, I would have

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IGenericRepository<MyProj.Data.SqlCe.User> userRepo = new GenericRepository<MyProj.Data.SqlCe.User>();
```

So I have to manually change to the correct assembly namespace to reference my entities when I switch databases.

Sorry if this has been done to death as haven't done one of these in awhile but what is the best/elegant solution for this scenario? The above one is very dirty looking. Also all my generic repository code is currently in a model folder in same namespace as the web app.

Comment: Why not use dependency injection and _inject_ the correct repository type based on the app configuration?

Comment: Thanks all, will investigate the suggestions and award the points after. thanks very much.

Comment: Why using repository pattern when EF has already  implemented it as DbSet?

Comment: Because I don't know the best solution so tried out generic to see what happens. Probably only useful for UnitTesting purposes. So I forget all that IGenericRepository stuff and put a global variable at the top of each controller to init the context? Like https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8. Problem is still the same though in how to best reference the same name entities in my controller when I switch between Azure and Sqlce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that springs to mind is to have a factory class to create the instances with a switch defined in the config file, e.g.

```
public DbRepositoryFactory
{    
    public IGenericRepository<User> GetUserRepository()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbSwitch"].Equals("Azure")
            ? new GenericRepository<MyProj.Data.SqlAzure.User>()
            : new GenericRepository<MyProj.Data.SqlCe.User>()
    }
}
```

Either that or to use reflection.

Comment: is it ok that GetUserRepository can return either SqlAzure.User or SqlCe.User ? Would I not have to specify the namespace of type User in the method definition ie public IGenericRepository<namespace.User>...) to get it to compile and hence have same problem..

Comment: Create a partial class which implements an interface containing the required properties. That would do the job.

Comment: Sorry don't quite get it. I'm getting 'cannot implicitly convert type' errors.Is this a kind of abstract factory pattern ? Would my controller be using properties (type repository) of an instance of this factory class ? An example would be very useful thanks very much.

Comment: Create an interface containing the properties for the User object which is common across the 2 db contexts, e.g. ``public IAmAUser { public guid UserId {get;set;} } ``. Then create partial classes for the Azure and CE user objects which implement the interface, e.g. ``public partial class MyProject.Data.SqlAzure.User : IAmAUser { }``. You should then be able to use the IAmAUser interface rather than a specific User object. Note there may be some entity framework attributes you need to add.

Comment: Going to award this for the effort in solving my problem. However in hindsight dependency injection and reflection is the way to go for this type of setup.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using generic repository, it won't know how to determine which user entity you want unless you tell it.

What you can do, create a factory that solves it for you. GenericRepositorySqlAzure and GenericRepositorySqlCe